# Heatmap in ggplot2 issue with fill

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, heatmap, fill

I'm trying to make a heatmap using ggplot2. What I want to be plotted is in the form of a matrix which is the result of a function.

Here is the data:

```
Image   A   B   C   D   E   F   
 1      3   23  45  23  45  90
 2      4   34  34  34  34  89
 3      34  33  24  89  23  67
 4      3   45  234 90  12  78
 5      78  89  34  23  12  56
 6      56  90  56  67  34  45
```

Here is the function:

```
vector_a <- names(master)[2:4] 
vector_b <- names(master)[5:6]

heatmap_prep <- function(dataframe, vector_a,vector_b){
    dummy <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=length(vector_a), ncol=length(vector_b)))
    for (i in 1:length(vector_a)){
                first_value <- dataframe[[ vector_a[i]  ]]
                # print(first_value)
            for(j in 1:length(vector_b)){
                    second_value <- dataframe[[ vector_b[j] ]]
 result <- cor(first_value, second_value, method = "spearman")
                    dummy [i,j] <- result
            }
        }

rownames(dummy) <- vector_a
return(as.matrix(dummy))
heatmap_data_matrix1 <- heatmap_prep(master,vector_a, vector_b)
```

Using the data in heatmap_data_matrix1, I want to create a heatmap using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
if (length(grep("ggplot2", (.packages() ))) == 0){
        library(ggplot2) 
    }

p <- ggplot(data = heatmap_data_matrix1, aes(x = vector_a, y = vector_b)
+ geom_tile(aes(fill = ))
```

However, this does not work. How should I reformat my data/code so this heatmap can be created? What should I put under "fill="?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to use loop? There are easier ways to plot heatmap using ggplot2

Comment: Yes, because I wanted to create a general script that can be used for multiple difference data sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to many of R functions being vectorized and that, for the most part, you don't need to pre-allocate or define a vector the for loop is unnecessary.  You can simply run `corr(x,y, method = "spearman")` without the complications of the loop.

Regarding your question of what to put in for fill, you'll need to reshape your data to the configuration that `ggplot2` uses (long format).

The `gather` function from `tidyr` does this, placing the rows/columns of the correlation into separate columns, and then using the r value for fill.

```
library(tidyverse) # for tidyr, tibble, ggplot2, and magrittr

heatmap_function <- function(df, a, b) {

  cor_data <- cor(df[a], df[b], method = "spearman") %>% 
    as.data.frame(rownames = a) %>% 
    rownames_to_column("x") %>% 
    gather(y, fill, -x)

  ggplot(cor_data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill)) +
    geom_tile()

}
```

This results in:

```
heatmap_function(master, c("A","B","C"), c("D","E"))
```

[image]